# How do you fire a blur() event in a Jest test in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a Native app, where I have a custom Input component on my Auth Screen that does it's own valididation and displays it's own error message.

Basically, when you click away from the input box, it displays the error message if the input is invalid (blur the input box). And I can confirm this happens when I test the app.

However, when I test for this in jest, the text never appears. I can't get the blur event to fire.
I've tried pressing it, then pressing a different input (on the AuthScreen component) This behavior does blur the first input in the live app, but not in the test.

```
 fireEvent.press(passwordInput);
 fireEvent.press(emailInput);
 await findByText('Please enter a valid password');
```

Next I tried hitting the return key, because in the live app, that does go to the next input, bluring the first. Did not work.

```
  fireEvent.press(emailInput);
  fireEvent.press(emailInput, { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 });
  await findByText('Please enter a valid password');
```

Finally, I tried refs on the Input component itself, this too did not work

```
const errorMessage = 'An error message';
it.only('It displays error message when the input is blurred', async () => {
  const inputRef = createRef();
  const { debug, findByText, getByPlaceholderText } = render(
    <Input
      errorText={errorMessage}
      placeholder="placeholder"
      ref={inputRef}
      onInputChange={jest.fn}
      initialValue=""
    />
  );
  const input = getByPlaceholderText('placeholder');

  inputRef.current.focus();
  fireEvent.changeText(input, 'text');
  inputRef.current.blur();
  debug();
  const errMsg = await findByText(errorMessage);
});
```

The input component:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import mergeRefs from 'react-merge-refs';

import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';

const INPUT_CHANGE = 'INPUT_CHANGE';
const INPUT_BLUR = 'INPUT_BLUR';

const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.value,
        isValid: action.isValid,
      };
    case INPUT_BLUR:
      return {
        ...state,
        touched: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    value: props.initialValue ? props.initialValue : '',
    isValid: props.initiallyValid,
    touched: props.initialValue ? true : false,
  });

  const { onInputChange, id } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    onInputChange(id, inputState.value, inputState.isValid);
  }, [inputState, onInputChange, id]);

  const textChangeHandler = text => {
    const emailRegex =
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    let isValid = true;
    if (props.required && text.trim().length === 0) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.email && !emailRegex.test(text.toLowerCase())) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.min != null && +text < props.min) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.max != null && +text > props.max) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    if (props.minLength != null && text.length < props.minLength) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    dispatch({ type: INPUT_CHANGE, value: text, isValid: isValid });
  };

  const lostFocusHandler = () => {
    debugger;
    dispatch({ type: INPUT_BLUR });
  };

  const inputRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={{ ...props.style, ...styles.container }}>
      <TextInput
        ref={mergeRefs([inputRef, ref])}
        {...props}
        value={inputState.value}
        onChangeText={textChangeHandler}
        onBlur={lostFocusHandler}
      />

      {!inputState.isValid && inputState.touched && (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>
          <View style={{ ...props.style, ...styles.errorContainer }}>
            <Text testID="Auth.errorMessage" style={styles.errorText}>
              {props.errorText}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  errorContainer: {
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  errorText: {
    color: Colors.danger[3],
    fontSize: 13,
  },
});

export default Input;
```

I've looked around, and there doesn't seem to be any examples of someone sucessfully blurring an input in a React Native test.